# mkdir -p for one path segment

Tags: macos, mkdir

I understand the use of `mkdir -p` for cases like: `mkdir -p foo/bar` 
where neither of those directories yet exists, which I was surprised to see someone using `mkdir -p bar`. Does it ever make sense to use -p when there is no `/` in the following argument, i.e. there is only one path segment?

My understanding is that `mkdir -p foo` is equivalent to `mkdir foo` in all cases. Is there a case I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mkdir foo` will report an error if a directory named "foo" already exists; `mkdir -p foo` will not. Essentially, in this case the `-p` just tells `mkdir` that it's ok if the directory already exists.